# Matplotlib: multipage PDF with rasterized plots

Tags: python, pdf, matplotlib

I generate a multipage pdf using the following code.
Since I will have around 3000 plots, 10 per pages. the pdf could become uge.
I though to substitute every plot with a jpg or pdf version. But I am not sure how to do it within PdfPage backend.

```
plots_per_page = 10
col_per_page = 1

with PdfPages('NewPDF.pdf') as pdf:
    for pgg in range(0,pages):

        fig = figure(figsize=(8,20) )
        gs1 = gridspec.GridSpec(plots_per_page//col_per_page, col_per_page)

        for i in arange(0,10):
            ax = fig.add_subplot(gs1[i])
            ax.bar(arange(20), random.normal(0,1,20), linewidth = 0.5)

        gs1.tight_layout(fig , h_pad=0.8, w_pad=0.8)
        axis('auto')

        savefig(pdf, format='pdf')
        close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a similar problem to this question, I think: [Rasterizing multiple elements in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12098331/rasterizing-multiple-elements-in-matplotlib)

As in [one of the answers there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12102852/1728179), use:

```
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, rasterized=True)
```

or do:

```
ax.set_rasterized(True)
```

You can then set the resolution for the plots if you want to nudge the filesize some more:

```
savefig(pdf, format='pdf', dpi=300)
```