# Closed lines in matplotlib contour plots

Tags: python, pdf, matplotlib, contour

When looking closely at contour plots made with matplotlib, I noticed that smaller contours have inaccurate endpoints which do not close perfectly in PDF figures.  Consider the minimal example:

```
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
x,y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-1,1,100), np.linspace(-1,1,100))
r = x*x + y*y
plt.contour(np.log(r))
plt.savefig("test.pdf")
```

The central part of the resulting test.pdf file, shown below, clearly shows the problem.  Is there a way to solve this or is it a bug/intrinsic inaccuracy of matploplib?

[image]

Comment: I get the same result using matplotlib 1.5.3.

Comment: @AngusWilliams Thank you for the double check.

Answer (score 4):

Disclaimer: this is more an **explanation + hack** than a real answer.

I believe that there is a fundamental problem the way matplotlib makes contour plots.  Essentially, all contours are collections of lines (`LineCollection`), while they should be collection of possibly closed lines (`PolyCollection`).  There might be good reasons why things are done this way, but in the simple example I made this choice clearly produces artifacts.  A not-very-nice solution is to convert a posteriori all `LineCollection`'s into `PolyCollection`'s.  This is what is done in the following code

```
from matplotlib.collections import PolyCollection

eps = 1e-5
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
x,y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-1,1,100), np.linspace(-1,1,100))
r = x*x + y*y
plt.contour(np.log(r/1.2))
ca = plt.gca()
N = len(ca.collections)
for n in range(N):
    c = ca.collections.pop(0)
    for s in c.get_segments():
        closed = (abs(s[0,0] - s[-1,0]) < eps) and (abs(s[0,1] - s[-1,1]) < eps)            
        p = PolyCollection([s], edgecolors=c.get_edgecolors(), 
                           linewidths=c.get_linewidths(), linestyles=c.get_linestyles(),
                           facecolors=c.get_facecolors(), closed=closed)
        ca.add_collection(p)
plt.savefig("test.pdf")
```

A zoom of the result obtained shows that everything is OK now:

[image]

Some care is taken to check if a contour is closed: in the present code, this is done with an approximate equality check for the first and last point: I am wandering if there is a better way to do this (perhaps matplotlib returns some data to check closed contours?).  In any case, again, this is hack: I would be happy to hear if anyone has a better solution (or has a way to fix this within matplotlib).

Answer (score 0):

So I just did the same thing, but got closed contours (see images). Did you check for any updates on the package?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
x,y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-1,1,100), np.linspace(-1,1,100))
r = x*x + y*y
plt.contour(np.log(r))
plt.show()
```

[Zoomed Out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVrXD.png)

[Zoomed In](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5P6n.png)

Comment: You are not making a PDF, which was part of the minimal example.  Try to make a PDF file, then zoom its central region with your PDF viewer, and tell me if you still see closed contours, please.

Comment: Although not a perfect solution, I found that when I rasterized the gaps became significantly smaller.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12098331/rasterizing-multiple-elements-in-matplotlib


http://www.astrobetter.com/blog/2014/01/17/slim-down-your-bloated-graphics/

Comment: Rasterizing is not very nice: the good thing of PDF figures is that they allow vector graphics, which (at least in principle) scales very well when I zoom it.